# What are these creeping cacti tendrils?

Tags: species-identification, botany

During a trek through a small forest-type area on the main island of Hawaii, I came across the following plant:

[image: plant]

It did not cover very much area from what I could tell (there was a continuation of the bed just behind me from where I took the picture). I believe it was near Punalu'u Beach but I can't say with certainty.

It's creepy, looks like a tractor load of snakes got loose, and something I find fascinating. Could someone tell me what this cactus-y, bed of vines-like plant is?

Comment: I don't know what plant this is (a closer picture would help) but I was surprised on a recent trip to Maui by the large number of large cactus invasions. Mostly central american jungle species, but some prickly pears too. Really unfortunate. Don't get me wrong, I like cactus, they just don't belong in Hawaii, in my opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It's creepy ... something I find fascinating.

Creepy & fascinating indeed!

> Could someone tell me what this cactus-y, bed of vines-like plant is?

This *is* a cactus, and I believe it belongs to the genus *[Hylocereus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hylocereus)*, possibly the species *H. undatus*.

[image]

As for distribution, *Hylocereus* are quite prevalent throughout Hawaii, and can also be found scattered throughout the globe.

[image]
*Hawaii is the leftmost blue dot. [image source](https://www.cabi.org/isc/datasheet/27317)*

More information about this plant can be found [here](http://www.iucnredlist.org/details/152183/0).